# Tab is displaying code in Address Bar

Tags: html, wordpress, tabs

I have the following code, and its displaying `#page-1`, `#page-2` in the url on the page, is there a way to remove this from the url? This is a tab menu when select displays what in the tabbed section.

```
<nav>
<div class="navmenu">         
<div id="profile-nav">
<ul id="profile-navigation" class="nav">
<li><a href="#page-1">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#page-2">Measurements</a></li>
<li><a href="#page-3">Pictures</a></li>
<li><a href="#page-4">Contact</a></li>
</ul>           
</div>
</div>
</nav>

<div class="content" id="page-1">
<h2>Page 1</h2>
<p>Text...</p>
</div>

<div class="content" id="page-2">
<h2>Page 2</h2>
<p>Text...</p>
</div>

<div class="content" id="page-3">
<h2>Page 3</h2>
<p>Text...</p>
</div>

<div class="content" id="page-4">
<h2>Page 4</h2>
<p>Text...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason `#page-1`, `#page-2` and so on are being appended to the URL is because this is how navigation by ID works; what your `<a>` links point to is the particular item within the DOM (in this case `div#page-x`), and that's just how that kind of linking works I'm afraid!

If you need to have all these pages available within the one DOM, without any page re-loading, you could consider a Javascript-based solution, which would clean up the URLs (well, it wouldn't affect the URL at all - not unless you asked it to), although navigation with Javascript is a bit of a minefield in terms of good SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tags would be there in the URL. You may try to do the same thing using scripts. Invoke the script on click on the tab, give the clicked tab a class, based on the active class, display the tab content. Example:

```
<ul id="profile-navigation" class="nav">
 <li><a href="javascript:showContent('page-1');">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:showContent('page-2');">Measurements</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:showContent('page-3');">Pictures</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:showContent('page-4');">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the script:

```
function showContent(id)
{
    jQuery('.content').css('display','none');
    jQuery('#'+id).css('display','block');
}
```